# Procedural style Rock Paper Scissors game using Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

I am a newbie to Python and am trying to do the Rock, Paper and Scissors game to revise my knowledge that I have earned so far.

Overview of the program:

- This is a two-player game
- Ask for player plays (including name, their choice: rock or paper or scissors using input)
- Print out a message of winner
- Ask if the user want to start a new game

This code is written in procedural style.

Can anyone show me some weaknesses in my code and how I can improve on them?

```
def beats(a, b): 
    tup = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    if (a == tup[1] and b == tup[2]) or (a == tup[2] and b == tup[1]):
        return tup[2]
    elif (a == tup[1] and b == tup[0]) or (a == tup[0] and b == tup[1]):
        return tup[1]
    elif (a == tup[0] and b == tup[2]) or (a == tup[2] and b == tup[0]):
        return tup[0]


def players_input():
    name = input('What is your name?: ')
    while True:
        decision = input('Paper, Rock, or Scissors?: ')
        if decision == 'rock' or decision == 'paper' or decision == 'scissors':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice! Try again!")
            continue
    return '{} chooses {}'.format(name, decision)


def play():
    player1 = players_input()
    player2 = players_input()
    print('{}\n{}'.format(player1, player2))
    name1, verb, decision1 = player1.split(" ")
    name2, verb, decision2 = player2.split(" ")
    returnvalue = beats(decision1.lower(), decision2.lower())
    if decision1.lower() == returnvalue and decision2.lower() != returnvalue:
        print('{} wins'.format(name1))
    elif decision2.lower() == returnvalue and decision1.lower() != returnvalue:
        print('{} wins'.format(name2))
    else:
        print('It\'s a tie')


def play_again():
    while True:
        choice = input('Do you want to continue?(Y/N): ')
        if choice.upper() == "Y":
            play()
        elif choice.upper() == "N":
            print("Game over")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input! Try again!")


play()
play_again()
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend simplifying:

```
if decision == 'rock' or decision == 'paper' or decision == 'scissors':
```

to:

```
if decision.lower() in ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors'):
```

This will check whether the decision exists in a given tuple.

This helps simplifying the idea "If a variable contains one of these values".

Another example is "If variable `x` contains either 1, 3, or 5." Instead of coding it like this:

```
if x == 5 or x == 3 or x == 1
```

It can be simplified into:

```
if x in (1, 3, 5)
```

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sometowngeek/cb18d338bd488c45fccefc86bb9a9b1d) to see my suggestion as a whole.

Comment: I do not catch the idea of `if x == 5 or x == 3 or x == 1`? What is x, 1, 3 and 5? Can you help me explain it?

Comment: I'm just using it as an example. It's another way of saying "If a variable holds one of these values."

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is good you are reviewing your knowledge. 
Secondly, I would like to add to [Sometowngeek](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/167335/142541)'s suggestion. Implement his one.

**Thirdly**, instead of writing:

> `name1, verb, decision1 = player1.split(" ")`

you could write:

```
name1, decision1 = player1.split(" chooses ")
```

I made some changes to your `play()` function:

```
def play():
    player1 = players_input()
    player2 = players_input()

    print('{}\n{}'.format(player1, player2))

    name1, decision1 = player1.split(" chooses ")
    name2, decision2 = player2.split(" chooses ")

    if decision1 == decision2:
        print('It\'s a tie')
    else:
        returnValue = beats(decision1, name1, decision2, name2)
        print('{} wins'.format(returnValue))
```

And some more changes to your `beats()` function:

```
def beats(a, name1, b, name2):
    tup = ('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
    if (a == tup[0] and b == tup[2]) or (a == tup[1] and b == tup[0]) or (a == tup[2] and b == tup[1]):
        return name1
    else:
        return name2
```

In `beats()` function, it is better to return the names of the players; so, you will not use `if` in your `play()` function.

Finally, good luck with your future coding!

Comment: I had thought that the split function can only be passed in a delimeter (like space, -, so on). Thank you, I have realized lots of things.

Comment: @BlahBlah, In the `beats()` method, there's a possibility of tie. Might want to add something to handle that. :)

Comment: @Sometowngeek, I believe I handled it in the `play()` function.  `if decision1 == decision2` is handling the tie. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("name?")
def players_input(player):
    while True:
    decision = input('Paper, Rock, or Scissors?: ')
    if decision == 'rock' or decision == 'paper' or decision == 'scissors':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice! Try again!")
        continue
return '{} chooses {}'.format(player, decision)
```

So you won't be prompted to input your name every time you play again.